# Different solution to `Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active`

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I've just migrated from MySQL to newer MariaDB and all my websites are now showing:

> Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.
>   Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code
>   is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query
>   buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I googled this error and tried doing what people suggested.

So I changed my code to use PDO's `closeCursor()`.
I tried using `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` and nothing works.

Comment: I don’t understand why this is downvoted. I had the same issue using MySQL with the same cause and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's how my constructor looked:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db . ';port=' . $port, $user, $pass, 
                array(
                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8;SET SESSION time_zone="system"', 
                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
                ));
```

I changed it to

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db . ';port=' . $port, $user, $pass, 
                array(
                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8, SESSION time_zone="system"',     
                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
                ));
```

and it does work now.

I am posting my solution here because all other places have "wrong" ones.

So the difference is instead of having

```
'SET NAMES utf8;SET SESSION time_zone="system"'
```

in `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` I have:

```
'SET NAMES utf8, SESSION time_zone="system"'
```

and everything's fine now.

Comment: actually, you should put utf8 into charset section of DSN. and also there is no point in using PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, as you can send any number of commands using just the regular query() method

Comment: @YourCommonSense Prior to PHP 5.3.6 charset in DSN was ignored so the above solution works even for older PHP. And using MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND instead of query() is just my choice.